# Setting up SQL server on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, database

I would like to set up a SQL server in AWS on an EC2 server. I originally wanted to use an RDS instance however we require the bulk admin privilege for some of our operations which is not allowed in RDS. I was wondering if it is possible to increase disk space after the instance has been constructed? Can EBS replace mirroring/replication? And any pointers would be greatly appreciated for going down this path.

Comment: Most of that you can (and should) test. My tentative answer would be: you can resize, but not without reboot. And EBS for mirror/replication: no, it is not atomic, and you can't easily access the backups.